# How can I filter by more than one value in the same column of a database - Django

Tags: python, html, django

right now I am building a website, where you can filter products by certain categories. I already build a filter, where i can filter by name, price and brand. Now I also want to filter by volume (at the moment, I just have beverages in my Database). But I want to have checkboxes, where I can select several volumes at the same time. For example, if the box with 0.2, 0.5 and 0.7 is checked, I want to filter by those volumes. I don't know how to filter by more than one value in the same column.

This is my Model:

```
class WhiskyContent(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.FloatField(default=20)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    picture = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    product_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shipping = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    volume = models.FloatField(default=20)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    shipping_requirements = models.FloatField(default=20)
    concentration = models.FloatField(default=20)
    price_with_shipping = models.FloatField(default=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

I build all my other filter forms with HTML and Bootstrap so I don't want to use Django forms, if its possible.

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Can you share the relevant model(s)?

Comment: So i can say that you have a Beverage and a Volume Model , the Beverage model have a volume ManyToManyField attribute , so you can write a view to get the beverages that have the selected volumes and display them in an html file

Comment: I edited my post and added my model

Comment: Take a look at [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), you can use it to filter with different values

Comment: @AndréAbbound this sounds nice, but i don't know how to work with ManyToManyFields. Can you give me an example, how to make use of it ? I realy struggle at this point :/. I hope you can help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe to merge querysets:

`WhiskyContent.objects.filter(volume=0.2) | WhiskyContent.objects.filter(volume=0.5) | WhiskyContent.objects.filter(volume=0.7)`

Comment: The problem is that it is not possible for me to use the or  ( | ) operator here. Because I want it like this: If someone search for a name and checks the checkboxes with the volume, lets say he checks 0.7 and 0.5 than i want to display the all objects with the name and with the volume 0.7 and 0.5. But when with the or operator, all